# Paypal-Mass Payments without emails adresses?

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to mass pay  people with payapl (using csv) without using email adresses (and without phone number)?
I.e. using some PayPal account number instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RECEIVERTYPE` variable to set the kind of information you're using to identify the receivers of your receiver.

The values for `RECEIVERTYPE` can be `UserID`, `PhoneNumber`, or `EmailAddress`

The `L_RECEIVERIDn` (the `UserID`) value would need to be the Payer ID for the buyer. To get that value you'll  need to get it from an Express Checkout transaction or have the account holder go to the Profile of their account to give it to you.

The `L_RECEIVERPHONEn` value would be the verified phone number on the account.